# Which files from Node.js app must be uploaded to a web-hosting?

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, browserify, web-hosting

Perhaps this is a silly question. It came out while I was learning how to set up a Node.js application for production on Ubuntu and digital ocean.

Let's say I have a simple data visualization app made in Node.js, using node modules such as `express`, `page`, `axios`, `yo-yo`, and `browserify` to compile my files.

I want to upload my app to a webhost that already exists.

This is the structure's app:

- node_modules
- public (app.js and app.css)
- src (header, home, and footer folders)
- views (index.pug file)
- gulpfile.js
- index.scss
- package.json
- server.js

Which files I need to upload in order to see my app as I see it in `localhost`?

Comment: hard to say without knowing exactly what your app does. If I were to guess I'd say all of them minus the node_modules, use npm install to download them on the server. I would add these in parallel to this webapp that already exists not to the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload everything.

What Maximelian says is true if you're going to run `npm install` again on your server. The standard way of doing this is sync the project using git (you can find a [.gitignore template for node.js here)](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore).

Once setup you'd do something like this on the server after making the commit locally, and pushing to your remote git repo:

```
git pull
npm install
npm start
```

If you were to just ftp the full working project including node_modules it would work just by running `npm start`. But the above method is what I'd recommend.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried your answer and it works, but I think this works in platforms such as Heroku, digital ocean, etc, What would you recommend me if I want to upload my files on `gh-pages` branch from github?

Comment: @RamiroTormenta from what I understand you can only host static files on github pages (you can't run node.js). I often recommend AWS free tier service and setting up an ubuntu server. That said Heroku and Digital Ocean will work just as well.

Comment: Thanks again, Philip!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly everything except node_modules, if you did not customized them. (rewrite some behavior after module installation)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.